# readdir over ftp returns false

Tags: php, ftp, opendir

I'm told that this code worked until recently. I don't know when.  I've boiled it down to the core problem:

```
$dir = "user:password@ftp.example.com/sub/sub";  // not really :-)
$resource = opendir($dir) or die("---bad directory---\n");
echo "<PRE>\$resource: ".print_r($resource,true)."</pre>\n";
$f = readdir($resource);
echo "<pre> dump:"; var_dump( $f ); echo"</pre>\n";
```

Anyway, if I put the value of $dir into a webbrowser, I'm immediately given a list of files.  So that is valid. var_dump on the $resource gives **Resource id #6**
while the $f is **bool(false)**

Like I said, this is the core- once fixed, I will reintroduce the while loop and the rest of the code. The server has been updated to 5.3.27, but I can't find anything along these lines that will cause this to fail.  I'm running 5.3.10 on my environment, and it fails here too. Any thoughts as to why this won't work any more?

btw. allow_url_fopen is true.

Thanks, Dave

Comment: do dir has "ftp://" at the beginning?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks for noticing.  It wasn't exactly cut-and-paste

Comment: I suppose it kind a passive/active mode problem, so you will need to change your code to use `ftp_###`  functions, as ftp:// wrapper works only in passive mode

Comment: I ended up doing that- I spent less time doing that than troubleshooting. It really, really bugs me that I have no real solution to this.   Thanks.